# projections of a vector space and a linear operator on this vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

i have a question about linear algebra,especially about

invariant subspaces and projections.the question is below:

let P be a projection of the vector space V over a field F

and let T be a linear operator on this vector space V.

i need to prove that the kernel of P and the range of P

are invariant under T if and on ly if

P commutes with T.

i need a hint or a solution for the question.

thanks for your help...

Comment: You should do each direction of the if and only if separately.  Have you tried either of the two directions yet?

Comment: i have not tried yet.i need to decide where to start

Comment: Start with proving that if $PT = TP$ then $T$ preserves $im \ P$ and $\ker P$.

Answer (score 1):

One direction is immediate. For the other:

You have the expansion $x = (I-P)x+Px$ for any $x$.

We want to show $(PT-TP)x = 0 $ for all $x$.

Use the above expansion, and note that if $y \in \ker P$, then $Ty \in \ker P$.
Furthermore, if $y \in {\cal R P}$, then $Ty \in {\cal R P}$, in particular, this means that $P T Px = TPx$.

Comment: thanks for your answer copper.hat.it will be very useful for me.